# SIP connections with TCP

Tags: sip

I am developing a small simple SIP server over TCP. I want to know if I should assume that all clients are connected to the SIP server or do I have to send a TCP connection if the client that is invited is not connected?

Comment: You should probably do some actual research on the protocol before asking questions like this.

Comment: Base flow (simplified): Client sends initial TCP request, server accepts TCP request and established the TCP connection. "Inside" the TCP connection the client will send a SIP INVITE. Based on that the client connects to the server via TCP, and not the server to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Basic flow of SIP server in you case may be following:

1. Clients REGISTER their `Contact` on your SIP server (with transport=tcp)
2. Server send INVITE to registered `Contact` when appropriate user is called.

What about TCP connection in this case. From NAT-traversal perspective it is better to keep TCP connection between server and client open. If NAT is out of scope then client MAY close connection and server will establish new connection to registered contact when client is INVITEd.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the server connected to clients always.

Client should also be able to make outgoing calls,
i mean client may want to send INVITE, Refresh-register, etc..